# Google Drive Folder to Email as Attachments

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form where I put the recipient's email "email" and an "intake number" as inputs.

I'm trying to code the script to run on form submission to search Google Drive for "intake number" as a folder name and send all items in that folder as attachments in an email to the recipient's email. I've figured out how to send an individual attachment (based on file ID), but I want to send multiple attachments from a specific folder as selected by the user. Is this possible?

This what I have so far but the code keeps getting tied up with the getFolderByName

```
 function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 2;
      var numRows = 3;
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var intakenumber = row[1];
        var emailaddress = row[2];
      }
      var files = 
    DriveApp.getFolderByName(intakenumber).getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  var attachments = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
    Logger.log(attachments)
  var message = "document attached";
  var subject = "test";
  var attachment = (attachments)
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailaddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      attachments: attachments
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can send an email with several attachment files. You can see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)). The value of ``attachments`` is an array. You can send several files using this. If this doesn't still not resolve your issue, can you provide your current script? I think that it will help users think of your solution. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I went ahead and added the code I'm working with to the original post.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If your issue was not solved yet, can we ask you about the issue about the current situation and errors? If your issue has already been solved, I'm glad.